# How do i do something every 1 hour just in the front side?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do the following:

When a user enters my program for the first time, a timestamp is saved, from then i want to do the following:

I have a list of players (let's say its a game of sort), who have a stamina of 5% (max is hundred).

Every hour i want their stamina to add 5% to itself.

I want this to be only on front side (angular.js), what are my options here?

Comment: you need use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: `window.setInterval(function(){player.addStamina();},1000*60*60);` in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

#### Angular JS

You should use `$interval`

```
$interval(augmentStamina, 3600*1000, 0, true, 5);
```

The 5th parameter is the `additional parameters to the executed function.` so in this case 5 to augment stamina by 5.

#### Vanilla JS

```
setInterval(augmentStamina, 3600*1000, 5);
```

Example of augmentStamina

```
function augmentStamina(value){
  stamina += value;
}
```

Comment: setInterval uses milliseconds, so that should be 3600*1000 instead. (60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds)